# Permissions denied for screen

Tags: command-line

[`screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) is a Linux tool for managing multiple shell windows. Upon running it in a headless version of Elementary I received the following error:

```
(watson)huey@terminus:~$ screen

Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you run a headless version of elementary? What purpose does this setup serve?

Comment: I run it in on a Chromebook for access to more capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/574773) primarily affecting server installs and other headless versions of Ubuntu.

It can be fixed with `sudo /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start`.

According to the bug description:

> I believe this is because
>   `/etc/rcS.d/S70screen-cleanup` is running via `upstart` much earlier than it expects to have run, and is failing to correctly clean up that directory.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup start
Don't have effect to me.